# Why is MariaDB/InnoDB on Linux reading DB files in 16KB blocks?

Tags: mariadb, innodb

SUBJ, and also, is it configurable? Debian package binary is stripped off symbols, all I can see is `pread64(..., 16384,...)` in the output of `perf`...

Comment: Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for your biggest table; there may be some advice we can give you.  Meanwhile, I am with Bill -- There is essentially no use case for changing the "page" size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the InnoDB page size is configurable. It's 16KB by default, because that's a good compromise for most applications. It allows rows to be large enough for typical uses, but it sets the unit of I/O at an appropriately fine-grained size.

See https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/does-innodb-page-size-matter/

Under specific workloads, it might give a small performance advantage to use a page size larger or smaller than 16KB, but only if you need to optimize disk I/O for reads or writes.

In general, it's better to *reduce* the frequency of disk I/O for reads or writes, by increasing the RAM allocated to the buffer pool. There's not as much need to optimize the actual I/O if you need to do it less frequently.

P.S.: I've used MySQL since 2001, but I've never encountered a need to use a custom page size.

Comment: It's an old app reading 20%+ from 100+GB tables from a 1+TB growing DB, trying to see if I can get away without rewriting it or loading the whole DB into RAM. Great answer and the link is just spot on, thanks Bill.

Comment: In my experience, it's rare that a database needs to be wholly resident in RAM. If you have a need for that, you should consider if it's time to switch to a different product, for example a data warehouse like Snowflake, or an in-memory database like TimesTen. Choosing the optimal data storage technology depends on what queries you need to optimize.